# Arkham Horror -- multiple investigators assisting in a combat?

Tags: arkham-horror

Despite **Arkham Horror** being a cooperative game, one of the glaring holes I noticed the first time I played was that it doesn't appear that multiple investigators can attack a single monster, and vice versa.

I've read the rules a couple of times, but wanted to make completely sure:

If two investigators are in the same space as a single monster, Investigator A has to either Evade the monster or pass a Horror check, then fight until they either win, flee or die.  If Investigator A flees or dies, Investigator B has the same option to either Evade or pass a Horror check, and fight as normal.  At no time can they somehow gang up together and add their Combat together against the monster, correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is correct. With the exception of the Final Battle, all combat is one-on-one. Investigators cannot team up against monsters, and multiple monsters in a single location do not team up against an investigator.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, as mentioned above, combat is one-on-one. Just wanted to add that there are rules for "team battles" at Arkham Investigations if you want to use them.

http://arkhaminvestigations.barkingdoginteractive.com/

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a look at those, thanks!